# What is last_sign_in_at used for in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

A standard User column in Devise is `last_sign_in_at`, which holds the previous value of `current_sign_in_at` when `current_sign_in_at` is updated.

Does `last_sign_in_at` have any utility for Devise's core functionality or Module functionality, or is it just there as a general convenience?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`last_sign_in_at` is the date and time the user signed in before their current session, which is `current_sign_in_at`. It will be `nil` if they haven't signed in or this is their first session.

A better name might have been *previous_sign_in_at* because it is not the time they signed in *last* (the current one), it's the time before that.

It might be helpful to illustrate its use: After sign in, if `updated_at` on your Terms & Conditions page is newer than the user's `last_sign_in_at` then redirect them to a terms acceptance page.

As with most attributes in the Trackable module, it is not used internally to Devise although it is maintained by it.

Comment: How to get the sign_out time in devise?

Comment: That is a different question and the trackable module will not help. You answer depends on what you want and what you have implemented already. You can create your own signed_out column in the database and set it in the sign out action of your controller sessions controller, or you can employ Devise's timeoutable module (if suitable) and examine the last_access attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to have a last_sign_out_at ? If not is it possible to implement the same?

Comment: I think this is the same question Arpit asked.

Answer (score 6):

Looking through the source code, it seems to just be an attribute of `Trackable` -- meant purely as a general convenience.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=last_sign_in_at

Additionally, the gemfile for Devise does not show anything that (I am guessing) would make use of that field.

So, just general convenience.